# How to write JavaScript in Qualtrics to auto-advance across items?

Tags: javascript, qualtrics

im a novice programmer with Java and Qualtrics.
i am looking for help in writing a JavaScript  to make respondents auto-advance after selecting an answer choice - in a multiple choice task with different items - once they make a response for one item i need them to automatically move to the next item.

i would greatly appreciate any help in this regard!
thanks so much
Yoed

Comment: please provide any code that you have tried to solve your problem

Comment: also, are you leveraging the Qualtrics API? If you get your survey https://api.qualtrics.com/docs/get-survey , you can render it however you like, and save the response and then import it back into Qualtrics https://api.qualtrics.com/docs/import-responses If you're not using their API, im not sure what options they would have available to add custom JS to a survey, but id be sceptical if it was allowed

Comment: this is the code i found and tried playing with: var that = this;
this.questionclick = function(event,element){
    if (element.type == 'radio')  {
       that.clickNextButton();
    }
}
however it doesn't seem to work to move across items,, or am i missing something?

Comment: You should edit your post and add your code to it.  That code advances to the next page, so it should work if you have one question per page.

Comment: i don't know how to edit this code to change it from moving to a question to moving to a different item. is there away to do this with the loop & merge or should i just use this code and have 90 different questions?

Comment: It would work the same way as a loop & merge or separate questions.

Answer (score 1):

Automatically shift to next question + No Next button (fastest way to navigate through survey)

1. Enter Javascript view on any question
2. Select and delete all code
3. Copy and paste the following

```js
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function()
{
    var that = this;
    this.questionclick = function(event,element){
        if (element.type == 'radio')  {
            that.clickNextButton();
        }
    }


});
```

4. Enter into HTML view for same question
5. Add the cursor to the bottom/end of the text
6. Add the following

```html
<style>
     #NextButton {display:none;}
</style>
```

7. Your all done. Preview to test